# Neo4j Desktop - Error connecting/stopping/starting databases - Database X can not be started

Tags: neo4j, cypher-shell

I have Neo4j Desktop 1.5.8 installed on a Windows PC. Created few databases and used the Query browser and Bloom as well. However, I keep encountering annoying issues like:

`Database xxx can not be started due to conflicts with external processes. To fix this problem, let us change these port configurations: bolt: xxxx -> xxxx`

Clicking `Fix configuration` doesn't work and keeps showing that error message. One solution (hack) that I found online was to find the process `Zulu Platform x64 Architecture` and terminate it. It works sometimes but most often it doesn't even appear in the Task Manager. I have also found that stopping/restarting a database results in forever `Stopping` operation.

I have tried:

- restarting Neo4j: works rarely
- keep hunting for the `Zulu Platform x64 Architecture`: works when I find it in taskmgr
- restarting the PC: works sometimes

Does anyone know of an actual fix to this problem? Any way, I can start/stop the database from command line, e.g., using cypher-shell or Python library?